# 'forbidden' for a person

Tags: sentence-construction

We use the adjective 'forbidden' for a thing that we must not use. Can a person be forbidden for a thing?
Like, can we say:

> People abiding by law are forbidden for jails.

Does this sentence make sense? Please note that here **'forbidden for'** refers to **"protected from"**.

Secondly,
See: My doctor has forbidden me sugar.

Subject+ forbid+ indirect obj+ direct obj

Here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forbid

So, what about this:

> Law forbids jail those people who abide by rules.

Subject+ forbid+ indirect obj+ direct obj

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use *forbidden for* to mean *protected from.* Your sentence sounds as though you think law-abiding people would like to go to jail if they were not forbidden to do so!

*My doctor has forbidden me sugar* really means *...forbidden me from consuming sugar.*

Your second sentence implies that 'jail' has an active desire to imprison people. You could possibly say *The law forbids the justice system from imprisoning law-abiding people.*